# three.js webgl custom shader sharing texture with new offset

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, vertex-shader

I am splitting a texture 1024 x 1024 over 32x32 tiles * 32, Im not sure if its possible to share the texture with an offset or would i need to create a new texture for each tile with the offset..

to create the offset i am using a uniform value = 32 * i and  updating the uniform through each loop instance of creating tile, all the tiles seem to be the same offset? as basically i wanting an image to appear like its one image not broken up into little tiles.But the current out-put is the same x,y-offset on all 32 tiles..Im using the vertex-shader with three.js r71...

Would i need to create a new texture for each tile with the offset?

```
      for ( j = 0; j < row; j ++ ) {

           for ( t = 0; t < col; t ++ ) {

                customUniforms.tX.value = tX; 
                customUniforms.tY.value = tY;
                console.log(customUniforms.tX.value);
                customUniforms.tX.needsUpdate = true;
                customUniforms.tY.needsUpdate = true;
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,mMaterial);// or new material
           }
       }

       //vertex shader :
       vec2 uvOffset = vUV + vec2( tX, tY) ;
```

Image example:

[image]

Each image should have an offset of 10 0r 20 px but they are all the same.... this is from using one texture..

As suggested i have tried to manipulate the uv on each object with out luck, it seems to make all the same vertexes have the same position for example 10x10 segmant plane all faces will be the same

```
    var geometry = [
    [ new THREE.PlaneGeometry( w, w ,64,64),50 ],
    [ new THREE.PlaneGeometry( w, w ,40,40), 500 ],
    [ new THREE.PlaneGeometry( w, w ,30,30), 850 ],
    [ new THREE.PlaneGeometry( w, w,16,16 ), 1200 ]
];

    geometry[0][0].faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

    for(var p = 0; p < geometry[0][0].faces.length; p++){ 
        geometry[0][0].faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2(0.0, 0.0),
        new THREE.Vector2(0.0, 1),
        new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 ), 
        new THREE.Vector2(1.0, 0.0)]);  
    }
```

image of this result, you will notice all vertices are the same when they shouldn't be

[image]

**Update again:**
I have to go through each vertices of faces as two triangles make a quad to avoid the above issue, I think i may have this solved... will update

**Last Update Hopfully:**
Below is the source code but i am lost making the algorithm display the texture as expected.

```
            /*
            j and t are rows & columns looping by 4x4 grid
            row = 4 col = 4;
            */

            for( i = 0; i < geometry.length; i ++ ) {
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry[ i ][ 0 ], customMaterial);
            mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
            var max     =  mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max;
            var min     =  mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min;
            var offset  = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x*t*j+w, 0- min.y*j+w);//here is my issue
            var range   = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x*row*2, max.y - min.y*col*2);
            mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
            var faces =  mesh.geometry.faces;

            for (p = 0; p <  mesh.geometry.faces.length ; p++) {
                var v1 =  mesh.geometry.vertices[faces[p].a];
                var v2 =  mesh.geometry.vertices[faces[p].b];
                var v3 =  mesh.geometry.vertices[faces[p].c];
                mesh.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
                new THREE.Vector2( ( v1.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v1.y + offset.y ) / range.y ),
                new THREE.Vector2( ( v2.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v2.y + offset.y ) / range.y ),
                new THREE.Vector2( ( v3.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v3.y + offset.y ) / range.y )
                ]);

            }
```

You will notice the below image in the red is seamless as the other tiles are not aligned with the texture.
[image]

Comment: What is preventing you from using 1024x1024? Is this texture being rendered on one mesh? Or maybe 32 separate quads?

Comment: 32x tiles, but all with an offset, i  wll upload a pic...

Comment: Does each tile have a separate material? If they are using the same material, you need to set the offset in the render loop, not in the creation.

Comment: It maybe in the vertex????, but i thought as i update the uniforms the call should change the tX , tY ...

Comment: Wouldn't you just change the UVs of each tile or am I missing something? Question is a little confusing.

Comment: each tile should have its own offset sharing the same texture, sharing same shader

Comment: the offset appears to happen but no effect on the texture itself..hard to debug

Comment: It appears though i have to use new materials on each as the uv changes it effects all objects... i may be best splitting the large texture up into 32x32 pieces as this would render better....Any better suggestions would be apreciated

Comment: As I said, you need to change the uniform values in the render loop for it to be different per object.

Comment: I will give it a go , and back to you

Comment: would you have an idea how i go about  that, cause the loops on 1 page and the render is on another? How could i tell the render each tile made update uniforms inside rendere

Comment: Your method seem to not too have any different outcome, i multiplied the uv through the render loop same result accoured

Comment: like I said, your question is a little confusing, especially your use of the word "offset"

Comment: You should be able to just adjust the texture coordinates per vertex of your geometry. Remember that UVs are a decimal in the range of 0 to 1. So if you want to use the top-left 512x512 square of a 1024x1024 texture, you need the UVs of your vertex to be [0,1], [0.5,1], [0.5,0.5], [0, 0.5]. (You might need to sort those based on your vertex order). Integer multiples will just wrap around (unless you change tiling behaviour).

Comment: Basically: If you're adding 64 to your UVs, you're really adding 64 full-texture-widths to the UV, not 64 texture-pixels. This ends up in the same spot. To offset 64 pixels on a 1024 pixel texture, you need to add 0.0625 to your UV coordinates. That said, you might have set up a different part of your shader (or another part of your JavaScript) to do the conversion from the provided uniform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
      var offset  = new THREE.Vector2(w - min.x-w+(w*t), w- min.y+w+(w*-j+w));
      var range   = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x*7, max.y - min.y*7);
```

if you could simplify answer will award *bounty* too: