# Clone shader Material three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I had issues with another question for a resolution Here, [three.js webgl custom shader sharing texture with new offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877032/three-js-webgl-custom-shader-sharing-texture-with-new-offset)..

After reading i am  concluding i may have to use the clone method();. Simple enough but i am sure im missing something as im getting a black rendered result on my mesh.

```
   originalM = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vShader' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fShader' ).textContent,
        wireframe: true,
        side: THREE.FrontSide 
  }   );


  for ( j = 0; j < row; j ++ ) {
       var shader2 =  originalM.clone();
       shader2.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( originalM.uniforms );
       shader2.needsUpdate = true;
       shader2.uniforms.tX.value = 0.20 * t;
       shader2.uniforms.tY.value = 0.20 * j;
       for ( i = 0; i < geometry.length; i ++ ) {
             var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry[ i ][ 0 ], shader2);
             group.add(mesh);
       }

  }
```

[image]