# BabylonJS Adding and positioning an image to an .obj

Tags: babylonjs

I'm partly through a 3D modelling application and am currently using `3JS`. However I've run into a rather difficult problem involving positioning images onto a complex object. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490489/how-to-decrease-and-increase-the-size-of-an-image-on-an-object-threejs) for a summary of what I'm attempting to achieve.

At this point in the project I'm rather concerned that it might take too long to achieve what I want with `3JS` so I was hoping that I could achieve the positioning of the images on the object in the scene quite easily using `BabylonJS`, albeit hoping the learning curve for `3D` stuff has already been overcome.

Can this be done in `BabylonJS` and if so does anyone have a link that will either answer my question or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you correctly, this is done relatively easy in `Babylon.js` using multimaterials.

I will try simplifying it - you want to have a single mesh (a box, for example), but set a different material properties (or better yet -  different material with the same textures) on each side of it.

An old (but still valid) tutorial can be found here - https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=283

You can also test it in my material editor , http://materialeditor.raananweber.com/ . you can set a multimaterial to each mesh using the "configure SubMeshes" button. If you take the cube, select `configure submeshes`and divide the cube to 6 equal submeshes, you will get the effect you want.

Comment: all links are outdated