# Why do two faces appear invisible in ThreeJs?

Tags: three.js, blender

I've an object in Blender. Because I want to do some UV-unwrapping using ThreeJS (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490489/how-to-decrease-and-increase-the-size-of-an-image-on-an-object-threejs)) I determined that I need merge two of the sides to correctly unwrap.

So before exporting the `.blend` as a `.obj` object I selected the `Tris to Quads` face option to create a square face for the two sides as opposed to it being made up of two triangles. Here's what it looked like in Blender:

[image]

But when I import the `.obj` and `.mtl` file into ThreeJs I get this:

[image]

Is this a problem to do with me not updating the material being added to the new object? 
The handles appearing white makes me think this is the case. If so how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: Are you sure normals are facing the correct way? (Outwards)? I remember there is a hotkey in Blender to recalculate all normals.

Comment: I recalculated the normals in Blender and then followed the same export process. Unfortunately the result is still the same.

Comment: Try setting the material to `side: THREE.DoubleSide`. If that helps, your problem has to do with the normal-directions. In blender you can enable displaying of normal-directions in the right-hand menu (select "Face normals in section "Mesh Display"). The automatic fix is in edit-mode, select all (shortcut <A>) and then via menu "Mesh" > "Normals" > "Recalculate Outside" (shortcut <Ctrl>+<N>).

Comment: I set the materials to THREE.DoubleSide in Blender as I installed a plugin for it a while ago. I also recalculated both the inside and outside normals. It worked actually. Thanks for that. Can you post it as an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see something like this, the first thing I usually do is to set the material to `side: THREE.DoubleSide`. If that helps, the problem has to do with the normal-directions (so the face is actually there but isn't rendered because it is facing away from you).

To fix this, you should try the following:

- In blender you can enable displaying of normal-directions in the right-hand menu (select "Face normals in section "Mesh Display").
- You should now see if any of the normals are pointing inwards/in the wrong direction.
- There is an automatic fix that works well for properly constructed meshes:

  - select object and switch into edit-mode (<Tab>)
  - select all vertices (shortcut &ltA>)
  - via menu "Mesh" > "Normals" > "Recalculate Outside" (shortcut <Ctrl>+<N>).