# ThreeJs Side of object partially invisible

Tags: three.js

I've asked this question before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673535/why-do-two-faces-appear-invisible-in-threejs), and the answer was to do with either using `THREE.DoubleSided` or recalculating the normals/switching the sides in Blender for an object which has sides that appear invisible. I have done both of these and the side that I'm using still appears partially invisible.

In Blender I deleted the outside side, selected two edges, created a new face in-between the ages and dragged it out and I got this result when rendered ThreeJS:[image]

I've followed the advice in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994944/transparent-objects-in-threejs?noredirect=1&lq=1) but nothing seems to do the job.

Any other advice as to what is happening here. Thanks

**EDIT**

I have the side appearing now but the text that I add to the side half skews like this:[image: Skewed Text]

Any idea as to why this is? Boop

Comment: check if changing renderorder helps.  Other stuffs which you may have tried include side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true and depthTest: false.

If you create a fiddle others can give a try.

Comment: just to be clear, setting `THREE.DoubleSided` does not help? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Looks like Face Culling issue. Make sure that your model's  surface are correct. You can test it with @gaitat offer but i don't recommend you to use it unless you really need double sided objects.

Comment: @AmriteshAnand I'll look into the render order some more - as i understand it the order is determined by distance from the camera - the farther away an object is the higher order it becomes.

Comment: @gaitat - yes I've tried that - in fact that's the default parameter I set when creating a new material for the object.

Comment: @SelimAbidin I'm attempting to correct the model in Blender - will post back soon.